# how to download a jar file and all of its referenced libraries from a website in java code

Tags: java, jar

I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852602/no-main-manifest-attribute-after-downloading-a-jar-file-in-java) that states a problem I had with a manifest error upon opening a jar file that has been downloaded from a website in java code. After that was cleared, I got new errors that stated some of the referenced libraries I had in my project were not in the jar file.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pircbotx/cap/CapHandler

The code that I used to download the jar program is in the link at the beginning of the post. How do I download not just the classes I wrote, but also the referenced libraries?

Comment: I guess the question you need to answer is, are the dependencies also available from the same source?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean to ask.

Comment: We can't answer that question for you, you need to ascertain that information from the web site you're trying to connect to